# Values from html input are not posting to html file

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysqli

So i have a website, and i am trying to test the new user register functionality.  I am not getting an output for any of the echos in my LogInHelper.php file.  The goal is to be able to enter information for a new user, post it to LogInHelper.php, see if the passwords entered are equal, and if they are not, update the result div to the error message.

this is my LogIn.php file containing the html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Ticket Log In</title>
        <script src = "../../jquery.js"></script>
<style>
body{
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}
#box {
    background:blue;
    text-align:center;
    padding:10px;
    color:white;
    width:500px;
    height:300px;
    margin: 0 auto;

}
#LogIn {
    background:blue;
    text-align:center;
    padding:10px;
    color:white;
    width:500px;
    height:300px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
</style>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#sub").click(function(){
            var fist_name = $("#firstname").val();
            var last_name = $("#lastname").val();
            var user_email = $("#email").val();
            var department_id = $("#department").val();
            var user_pass = $("#pass").val();
            var user_pass2 = $("#pass2").val();
            $.post("LogInHelper.php",{firstname:first_name,lastname:last_name,email:user_email,department:department_id,pass:user_pass,pass2:user_pass2},function(data){
                $("#result").html(data);
            });
        });
        $("#sub2").click(function(){
            var loginuser_email = $("#loginemail").val();
            var loginuser_pass = $("#loginpass").val();
            $.post("LogInHelper.php",{loginemail:loginuser_email,loginpass:loginuser_pass},function(data){
                $("#result2").html(data);
            });
        });
        $('#box').hide();
        $('.new').click(function() {
            $('#box').toggle();
            $('#LogIn').toggle();
});
    });
</script>
    </head>
<body>
    <div id="box">
        <input type ="submit" class = "new" value = "New User Register">
        <h2>New User Register Here:</h2>
        <input type ="text" name="firstname" id="firstname" placeholder="Enter Your First Name"/></br>
        <input type ="text" name="lastname" id="lastname" placeholder="Enter Your Last Name"/></br>
        <input type ="text" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Enter Your email"/></br>
        <form action="LogInHelper.php" method="post">
        <select id = "department" name = "department">
        <?php 
                    $servername = "localhost";
                    $username = "quantco_Ted";
                    $password = "Quantum1";
                    $database = "quantco_Interns";

                    $con = mysqli_connect($servername,$username,$password,$database);
                        if($con->connect_error){
                        die("Connection failed " . $con->connect_error);
                    } 
                    $sql = "select Department_name,id from Department";
                    $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
                    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
                        $department = $row['Department_name'];
                        $id = $row['id'];
                        echo "<option value = '$id'>$department</option>";
                    }
        ?></select></form>
        <input type ="password" name="pass" id="pass" placeholder="Enter Your Password"/>
        <input type ="password" name="pass2" id="pass2" placeholder="Re-Enter Your Password"/>
        </br></br>
        <input type ="submit" name = "sub" value = "Register" id = "sub"/>
        <div id="result"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="LogIn">
        <input type ="submit" class = "new" value = "New User Register">
        <h2>Registered User Log In:</h2>
        <input type ="text" name="loginemail" id="loginemail" placeholder="Enter Your Email"/></br>
        <input type ="password" name="loginpass" id="loginpass" placeholder="Enter Your Password"/>
        </br></br>


        <input type ="submit" name = "sub2" value = "Submit" id = "sub2"/>
        <div id="result2"></div>
    </div>
</body>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is my LogInHelper file that receives the posts:

```
<?php
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "user";
    $password = "pass";
    $database = "db";

    $con = mysqli_connect($servername,$username,$password,$database);

    if($con->connect_error){
        die("Connection failed " . $con->connect_error);
    }

    $firstname = $_POST['firstname'];
    $lastname = $_POST['lastname'];
    $id = $_POST['department'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $pass = md5($_POST['pass']);
    $pass2 = md5($_POST['pass2']);

    echo $firstname;
    echo $lastname;
    echo $id;
    echo $email;
    echo $pass;
    echo $pass2;


    $sel = "select * from Employee where email='$email'";
    $run = mysqli_query($con,$sel);
    $check_email = mysqli_num_rows($run);

    if(!($pass==$pass2)){
        echo "<h2>Your emails do not match, please try again!</h2>";
        exit();
    }
    else if($check_email==1){
        echo "<h2>This email is already registered, please try another!</h2>";
        exit();
    }
    else{
        $insert = "insert into Employee (email, first, last, department_id,pass,) values ('$email','$firstname','$lastname','$id', '$pass')";
        $run_insert = mysqli_query($con,$insert);
        if($run_insert){
            echo "<h2>Registration Successful, Thanks!</h2>";
        }
    }
    mysqli_close($con);

?>
```

Comment: `var fist_name`? Unless you're a profession boxer, naming your fists is just... weird. Oh, and lovely [sql injection attack](http://bobby-tables.com) vulnerabilities...

Comment: * Professional boxer....and @lazersquids mcgee, you should read about object oriented `mysqli` and prepared statements: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php

Comment: @MarcB where are vulnerabilities?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have check your  `$("#sub").click(function(){` and found that you have **typo** mistake in   `var fist_name = $("#firstname").val();` so it should be  `var first_name = $("#firstname").val();`

Please update this after that it will work